# Changing table cell colour based on content - Empty cell above is breaking this code

Tags: javascript

I have this Javascript on my page, to change the font colour and background colour of a cell depending on the contents. It works fine when all the cells above contain a value. However, when any of the cells above in this column are blank, the whole column doesn't get the formatting applied.

Any ideas? Thanks.

```
var allTableCells = document.getElementsByClassName("colhomeaway");

for(var i = 0, max = allTableCells.length; i < max; i++) {
   var node = allTableCells[i];

   //get the text from the first child node - which should be a text node
     var currentText = node.childNodes[0].nodeValue; 

   //check for contents and assign this table cell's background color accordingly 
   if (currentText === "H") {
      node.style.backgroundColor = "#000099";
      node.style.color = "white";
  node.style.fontWeight = "bold";}
   else     
   if (currentText === "A"){
        node.style.backgroundColor = "#99ffff";
        node.style.color = "black";
    node.style.fontWeight = "bold";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
   else if(currentTExt === "" or isNaN(currentText) == false){

    }
```

This deal with the empty cells

Answer (score 0):

Table cells don't format properly when they are blank.  Using one of the solutions below, you won't have to change your javascript at all.  Hopefully you can use one of these techniques.

Two different solutions to this issue as outlined in [this link](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/HTML/emptycells.html).

CSS fix:

```
table { empty-cells: show; }
```

Non breaking space fix:

```
<td>&nbsp;</td>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the CSS method, doesn't seem to work, and I don't really want to have to but  '&nbsp' in each empty cell.